# js recursive function that returns a nested json

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I'm trying to create a recursive function that will produce a nested structure of items.
Each of the items in this file has a pointer for it's children and a stop value as you can see in here:

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "next_1": 2,
        "next_2": 3,
        "stop": false
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "next_1": 3,
        "next_2": 4,
        "stop": false
    },
    "3": {
        "id": 3,
        "stop": true
    },
    "4": {
        "id": 4,
        "stop": true
    }
}
```

this recursive function should get a start index which it will build the tree from and return a nested dictionary that looks like this:

```
{
    1: {
        2: {
            3: {},
            4: {}
        },
        3: {}
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried thus far?

Comment: and what is your ultimate goal? is this an assignment?

Comment: my goal is to create a visual tree from this json, Iv'e tried many things but I couldn't figure out a way to do it properly @DerekPollard

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
const data = {
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "next_1": 2,
        "next_2": 3,
        "stop": false
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "next_1": 3,
        "next_2": 4,
        "stop": false
    },
    "3": {
        "id": 3,
        "stop": true
    },
    "4": {
        "id": 4,
        "stop": true
    }
};


function build(root, idx) {
  const item = root[idx];
  const result = {};
  if(!item.stop) {
    result[item.next_1] = build(root, item.next_1);
    result[item.next_2] = build(root, item.next_2);
  }
  
  return result;
}

alert(JSON.stringify(build(data, 1)));
```